# Is there an active IRC channel dedicated to project management?

Tags: communication

Well, the question is the title. Are there any active channels for discussion about PM? i'm currently hanging on irc.freenode.net and it would be great to have a place to ask questions live.

Answer (score 1):

This channel is for people involved in building project management software for the community:

> "#PMS ← Project Management Software Channel where pms activity is published in real time"

I don't see many channels targeting Project Management in general; however, this page does offer some tips on how to find IRC channels that you may be interested in:

[IRC Channels](http://rbose.org/wiki/IRC/Channels)

Comment: Very few specifics out there - +1 @jmort

Comment: hmmm...this seems outdated. I went there and got "Practical Music Search"